# how to set values to combobox dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

this is how i set value to a combobox using dwr call,

`var reportID = '<%=reportid%>';
    var reportName = '<%=reportname%>';
    loadReportNames(reportUserID);`

```
function loadReportNames(reportUserID){
    CustomiseReportAction.getReportNames(reportUserID, addReportNamesDropDown);
}
function addReportNamesDropDown(resultMap){
    dwr.util.removeAllOptions("reportnames");
    dwr.util.addOptions("reportnames",resultMap);
}
```

after loading the combo box i set values to loaded combo like this,

```
document.getElementById("reportnames").value=reportID;
```

but the reportID is not set,

what could be the problem please help me to resolve this.

```
UPDATE :

function addCombo() {
    var reportID = '<%=reportid%>';
    var reportName = '<%=reportname%>';
    var textb = document.getElementById("reportnames");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = reportName;
    option.value = reportID;
    option.selected="selected";
    try {
        textb.add(option, null); //Standard
    }catch(error) {
        textb.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

used above method it gives me no exception but no results.

Regards

Comment: If the `var reportID =`... is placed in a function, remove the `var` before the `reportID =`...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error using the updated info. The option has the proper `'<%=reportname%>'` text and `'<%=reportid%>'` value. By "*reportID is not set*", do you meant that the result after the option has been added, it has no text and no value?

Comment: those two come from session, which are already present in combobox say `reportid =1 and reportname = sample` anyway thanks for the interest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not removed the value rather i added the following code, it solved me the problem.

```
function addCombo() {
    var reportID = '<%=reportid%>';
    var options= document.getElementById('reportnames').options;
    for (var i= 0, n= options.length; i < n ; i++) {
        if (options[i].value==reportID) {
            document.getElementById("reportnames").selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: I just double checked and it should work like you did it, so disregard my original post. Are you sure the content of reportID exactly matches one of the options? If its a number, not a string, you might want to try

```
document.getElementById("reportnames").value = "" + reportID;
```

**Original**:
To set the selected option of a combobox (assuming you mean html "select") you need to set the "selected" attribute of the desired option to true.

```
var select = document.getElementById("reportnames");
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
{
    if (...)
        select.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

You will need some way to identify the option, I'd do it by saving the reportID in it. Then you could replace the ... with:

```
select.options[i].ReportId == reportID
```

If you set the reportID as the "id"-attribute of each option you could even do it like this:

```
document.getElementById(reportID).selected = true;
```

Comment: don't understand your answer, `reportnames` is a combo box reportID is the value which returned `ex : 1 or 2 or etc` already there are some values in the combo box which has got the same values of `reportID` so i want to set that value and make it selected.

Comment: in my updated question i have given one method which is working fine but adds duplicate value. how to avoid this

Comment: I have an idea: if dwr only does not set the reportID as a value to the options, you sould try your original aproach with document.getElementById("reportnames").value=reportName;

Comment: Could you post the generated html? That might help to figure out whats wrong. Regarding your updated post: your function adds a duplicate value, because you are creating one. You are not marking an existing value selected, but creating one and adding it.