# onclick event of button requires double click

Tags: xpages

I have a viewPanel using DB2 for the datasource.  I have created a comboBox containing all the possible viewPanel columns, a radioGroup to select ASC or DESC, a comboBox containing all the possible viewPanel columns with an onchange event to partially update the values in another comboBox, and a final comboBox that has all the values from DB2 according to the previous comboBox value that has an onchange event to partially update the viewPanel.

The onclick event for my button has this code and does a partial update of the viewPanel:

```
var sort:String = getComponent('comboBox1').getValue();
var order:String = getComponent('radioGroup1').getValue();
var vp = getComponent('panel_container').getData()[0];
vp.setDefaultOrderBy(sort + " " + order)
```

The problem is that I have to click the button twice to get the code to actually run.  The first click is ensuring the onchange event is fired, then the second click activates the code.  I have tried to use Full Update and checking the 'Set partial execution mode' with the partial update.

How do I get the onclick event for my button to work on the first click?

Comment: Did you try merging the code together in the onClick?

Answer (score 1):

Too much event tango :-) Here is what I would do:

- bind your combo boxes to viewScope variables. That's more robust than getValue() and allows to change the UI later (fancy some d&d)
- use the combo box client side, not the server side onChange() event. This would require all values to be send down eg via Ajax
- when you click the button make sure the fields are inside the panel you refresh

Hope that helps

Comment: bullets 1 & 3 no problem.

So, use Ajax on the client side to call a SQL statement to get my data from the DB2 table for my second comboBox?

Comment: Depends how massive your data is. Let's say you have 50 choices in box one, each with 50 choices in box two, then you have 2500 values. Make them 30 chars long that gives you 75k of data - not much actually. I would transmit them all in one go and do a full local selection. You could even save them in the HTML local store if they don't change in a session

Comment: I am trying to use client side code in my onchange event to call a SSJS function to put the valid values into a viewScope and refresh the combobox which is getting its values from that viewScope, but it isn't working.

onchange code:
    "#{javascript:getFilterByValue('comboBox2')}";
    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:comboBox3}","")

see SSJS code in additional comment

Comment: getFilterByValues SSJS  
`var getFilterByValues = function (comboID:string) {  
var itemList:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector;  
var filter = getComponent(comboID).getValue();  
dBar.info("Library: " + filter);  
try {  
if(filter == "Select Column" || filter == null) {  
itemList.add("Select Value");  
viewScope.put('filterby',itemList);  
dBar.info("No filter selected");  
} else {  
itemList.add("Select Value");  
itemList.add(@JdbcDbColumn("db2","TECH.TBSCRA_DEMO",filter,"",filter));  
viewScope.put('filterby',@Unique(itemList));  
}  
} catch (e) {  
dBar.info(e.toString());  
}
}`

Comment: what I have noticed is that the **"#{javascript:getFilterByValues('comboBox2')}";** line is running before I have ever changed the respective comboBox value

Comment: #{javascript is server side code, can't be client side. I would really use client side only. If you can't (due to size) load all possible values upfront, do an ajax call to replace the values on the client. For replacement code see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455981/how-to-set-values-to-combobox-dynamically-in-javascript